# Weird RequireJS Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: requirejs, marionette

this is very weird to me when I hit this error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: css is not defined`

and here is the code

```
define(function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var $          = require("jquery")
        _          = require("underscore"),
        Backbone   = require("backbone"),
        Marionette = require("backbone.marionette"),
        css        = require("css!style/toggle-switch"),
        tpl        = require("text!tpl/ViewPlan/listOut_instrument.html");

    return Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    });
});
```

what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: What line cause the error you show in your question?

Comment: `css        = require("css!style/toggle-switch")`

Comment: Add your RequireJS configuration to your question.

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS intentionally doesn't support loading style-sheets since a number of mainstream browsers don't notify when a style sheet is loaded. See [this](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css).

You can however roll your own (as found in the link above):

```
function loadCss(url) { 
  var link = document.createElement("link");
  link.type = "text/css"; 
  link.rel = "stylesheet"; 
  link.href = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link); 
}
```

Comment: by the way, if I remove the css line, then the next line will trigger the error. Anyone experience this?

Comment: Are you sure you configured the RequireJS `baseUrl` correctly? See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles